# Convert JSON string to RSA public key

Tags: java, json, spring-security

How can I convert a JSON string to RSA public key

or

```
String s = "AAA";
```

want to convert `s` to public Key

```
getPublicKey(
    jArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("e").getAsString(), 
    jArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("n").getAsString()
)


public static PublicKey getPublicKey (String modulusB64u, String exponentB64u)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException{

    //conversion to BigInteger. I have transformed to Hex because new BigDecimal(byte) does not work for me

    byte exponentB[] = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(exponentB64u);
    byte modulusB[] = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(modulusB64u);
    BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(toHexFromBytes(exponentB), 16);
    BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(toHexFromBytes(modulusB), 16);

    //Build the public key
    RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pub = factory.generatePublic(spec);
    return pub;
}
```

Instead of generating the public key, I want to convert the value of JSON string to public key.

Comment: Not sure what you mean in this question. By JSON do you mean JWK ? or any random JSON? RSA uses public and private keys, you need a private key to generate the public one, or at least two parts of it, as your code makes evident: modulus and exponent. You can't generate a public key from a random string, at least not a usable one.

Comment: @leoconco 's comment is right.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my public key i am reading from a url so i am parsing the response into a JSON string so now i convert this string to public key so i can validate a JWT token

Comment: I am using  Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initVerify(publicKey);
        sig.update(signedData.getBytes()); to validate JWT token the public key is declared as PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKey (modulusB64u,exponentB64u);      The getPublicKey method is geneartes the value of jArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("x5c").getAsString()

Comment: so how can i convert jArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("x5c").getAsString() to publicKey

Comment: any inputs here will be greatly appriciated